# validator shows, but button executes server code

Tags: asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

Something seems to be broken...I have a asp textbox in my Web Forms application, that has a Required Field Validator. If the textbox is empty, it shows the validator but also executes the server code, in that case code for insert into a table:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <asp:Label ID="lblPName" runat="server" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label" Text="Category Name"></asp:Label>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCategoryName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" CssClass="text-danger" runat="server" ErrorMessage="This Field is required" ControlToValidate="txtCategoryName"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Button code:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <asp:Button ID="btnAddCategory" CssClass="btn btn-default" runat="server" Text="Add" onclick="btnAddCategory_Click" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

And my server side code for inserting data:

```
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into tblCategories values(@CategoryName)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CategoryName", txtCategoryName.Text);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            txtCategoryName.Text = string.Empty;
        }
        BindCategoryRepeater();
```

Any reason why something like that would happen?

Comment: i added Page.Validate() to my button click event, and then I check if Page.IsValid and it shows FALSE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference: [RequiredFieldValidator Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples)

Add an if else with Page.IsValid in your server side code

```
if(Page.IsValid)
{
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into tblCategories values(@CategoryName)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CategoryName", txtCategoryName.Text);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        txtCategoryName.Text = string.Empty;
    }
    BindCategoryRepeater();
}
else
{
    //handle the error
}
```

Comment: why doesn't the required field validator execute first, why do i need to do it on server side like this.

Comment: Validation happens just after Page_Load but before the event handlers.  The page loads the controls, checks to see if there is text in the textbox, sets the Page.IsValid property, then attempts to execute the event.  See asp.net page life cycle https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178472(v=vs.100).

Comment: Also to do client side validation you would have to attach a JavaScript/jQuery event to the button and if the textbox is empty prevent postback and show an error.  The asp:RequiredFieldValidator is server side validation.  I typically do both.

Answer (score 0):

Add Validation Group in Button and RequiredFieldValidator :

```
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" CssClass="text-danger" runat="server" ErrorMessage="This Field is required" ValidationGroup="test" ControlToValidate="txtCategoryName"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

 <asp:Button ID="btnAddCategory" CssClass="btn btn-default" runat="server" Text="Add" onclick="btnAddCategory_Click" ValidationGroup="test"  />
```

Comment: Added Validation group as you showed but still executes server code

Comment: I added the same code to my controls, and what happens is, I click the button, the code executes, and then I see the Error Message. But there is a postback

Comment: add breakpoint on page_load and your button click. if you have click on button and check where breakpoint hit

Comment: Page_load gets hit when the page load, makes sense. When I click the button - i do Page.Validate(), then If (Page.IsValid) and this is FALSE, I simply added an ELSE statement this way it doesn't execute the server code. What I don't understand it, is why do I have to do Page.IsValid - if the required field validator is a client side validation, and it clearly fails

Comment: add this in page load:  if(!IsPostBack)

Comment: I do have this in Page_Load. What code am I supposed to add in the if (!IsPostBack) ?

Comment: show me your complete code of page load,button click